# [MSBuild]::Add invocation returns error MSB4186

Tags: build, msbuild, build-automation, versioning

MSBuild engine returns error MSB4186 for '$([MSBuild]::Add($(OldRevision), 1))' statement.
I'm using an example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx), but it does not work for me:

```
error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax:
"[MSBuild]::Add($(OldRevision), 1)". Input string was not in a correct format.
Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()),
e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`))
```

Here is what I'm trying to perform:

```
<CreateProperty Value="$([MSBuild]::Add($(OldRevision), 1))">
  <Output
      TaskParameter="Value"
      PropertyName="NewRevision" />
</CreateProperty>
```

I wonder what is tha proper syntax for it

p.s. yes, I'm using MSBuild 4.5

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it is something to do with `$(OldRevision)` being treated like a string. The following works for me: `<Message Text="Adding: $([MSBuild]::Add(2,3))"/>`, but not when I replace 2 and 3 with properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got this property syntax right, it is just not working in CreateProperty task. CreateProperty function is deprecated, there are very few reasons to use it.

This simpler property syntax works for me:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <NewVersion>$([MSBuild]::Add($(OldVersion), 1))</NewVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Also this works as well (inside any target):

```
<Message Text="OldVersion=$(OldVersion), NewVersion=$([MSBuild]::Add($(OldVersion), 1))" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me either. Same err. So, I simply returned to 'old good' 'Version' task